# Java - can't read ¬Ö (special character ) and print it

Tags: java, file, utf-8, character, utf-16

I am working with a txt file where I have text that looks like the following:
superman is the grand master of all legal highs¬Ö[testim]

I am trying to read this text, and print it out in another document, but when I print, it prints something like this
superman is the grand master of all legal highs 
 [testim]

I want to print the exact thing to the document, could you help me?
Here is my code:

```
    BufferedReader inputStream = null;
    PrintWriter outputStream = null;

    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File("completeTextFile"));
    inputStream = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis, "UTF-8"));
    outputStream = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("partSplit.txt"));

    String line;
    while ((line = inputStream.readLine()) != null) {
        String[] split = line.split("\\s+");
        int num = split.length;
```

After I split the file by space, I then want to put the above words together, but then it only prints the text in two lines without the special character.  I tried to look through StackOverflow, and tried to use UTF-8, but it still didn't work.  I tried to use UTF-16, then Java Heap Space not enough problem keep occurring, even after I set -Xms512M -Xmx2048M.

If you can help me figure out how to read a file with this special character, and then print the line of text as it is on one line, that would be great!

Edit:
Here is how I'm printing:
                for (int b = 11; b < num - 6; b++) {
                    outputStream.print(split[b] + " ");
                }
                outputStream.print(split[num - 6] + "\t");

Comment: (1) You haven't shown the code where you're actually writing it out.  (2) Is your initial file actually encoded in UTF-8 or something else?  (3) `inputStream` and `outputStream` are terrible variable names for things that are not an `InputStream` and an `OutputStream`.

Comment: `BufferedReader.readLine()` will removes trailing newlines. You may want to seek an alternative method or append your own newlines.

Comment: I actually don't know whether my file is in UTF-8 or not. I will definitely change the variable names!  Thanks for the tip.

Comment: "I have text that looks like" mean that your text editor has used some encoding to interpret whatever bytes it found. What are the *bytes* in the file?

Comment: @KarolS umm, do you know how I can find the bytes in the file?  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

try using other encoding like below...

```
inputStream = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis, "ISO-8859-1"));
```

you can set the encoding of the output with this constructor..

```
outputStream =  new PrintWriter("partSplit.txt","ISO-8859-1");
```

Comment: Thank you so much!  It actually worked for a bit, so it printed "superman is the grand master of all legal highs Â /n[testim]"

Comment: I add the constructor to outputstream with the charset, take a look in the answer

Comment: Thank you!  It worked really well since now all text are on the same line, but there is still one issue that "¬Ö" shows up as "Â…" Do you know if it's possible to fix this?  Again, thank you so much for your help!

Comment: can you upload the input file or a sample in somewhere public like docs, dropbox? I copy the text from this page and the chars are printed okay. We need to know what encoding your file has.